# Getting access denied when uploading an s3 file using Ink (FilePicker)

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io

We're using the Ink FilePicker, which works great for us, except for one specific use case. When uploading via a URL, and specifying a link to an s3 file - we get access denied error. Other links work fine, other HTTPS links work fine well. The bucket policy was set to make all uploads public, as per FilePicker documentation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created IAM permissions as per FilePicker recommendations:
https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#custom-s3

And you will need to set up those credentials correctly in FilePicker.

You will need that to get permission. FilePicker also has a [more detailed page and video](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/page/s3/) on how to set up S3 correctly.

Comment: Hi Suman, thanks for taking the time. The permissions were fine - this ended up to be a bug on FilePicker side, of not encoding the url they return after upload.